# Adding angular build "dist" file to node js server.js

Tags: node.js, angular, express, heroku, mean-stack

I'm trying to deploy my MEAN stack app to heroku. I successfully committed the app but I can't seem to connect my ng build "dist" file to my server.js file.

here is my server.js code where i'm trying to add the file:

```
var distDir = __dirname + "/dist/";

app.use(express.static(distDir));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Serve static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/outputPath'));

// Send all requests to index.html
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/outputPath/index.html'));
});

// default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)
```

Where `outputPath` is the value of your `outputPath` in your `angular.json` file (projects -> architect -> build -> options -> outputPath).

Comment: getting this error now : "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/mattcharnock/Documents/websites/paysocialapp/outputPath/index.html'"

Comment: you need to change outputPath. I explained it in the comment under.

Comment: of course I assume that you built your project with ng build --prod before.

Comment: it worked. but now it won't serve any of the API endpoints I created

Comment: You have to enable CORS in your backend project if you're serving the backend from another Domain. Do you host your front end and backend in the same project? If yes, just prefix all your backend endpoints with something like /api . For a SPA you want to redirect all requests to your index.html, expect for paths that start with /api.